# My onItemAtEndLoaded is getting triggered after the onZeroItemsLoaded

Tags: android, android-paging

I have this strange behavior where the onItemAtEndLoaded is getting triggered after the onZeroItemsLoaded so the recycler view keeps loading and does not stop. I have the project in the GitHub can someone please help me, I spent days in this. Can someone please take a look?

```
https://github.com/JosePedroNobre/ProductHunter
```

This is my  BoundaryCall class

```
class RepoBoundaryCallback(private val day:String,
                           private val service: PHService,
                           private val cache:PHLocalCache) : PagedList.BoundaryCallback<Post>()  {


    // keep the last requested page.
    // When the request is successful, increment the page number.
    private var lastRequestedPage = 1

    private val _networkErrors = MutableLiveData<String>()

    // LiveData of network errors.
    val networkErrors: LiveData<String>
        get() = _networkErrors

    // avoid triggering multiple requests in the same time
    private var isRequestInProgress = false

    /**
     * This method is called at the very beggining
     */
    override fun onZeroItemsLoaded() {
        requestAndSaveData()
    }

    /**
     * This method will tell when the user reached the end of the recycler view
     */
    override fun onItemAtEndLoaded(itemAtEnd: Post) {

        requestAndSaveData()
        //TODO resolver este bug
        //ele aqui sabe que chegou ao fim , o problema desta API é que nao dá o total de páginas
        // e quando ultrapassa as paginas que deve ela dá dados repetidos
        //  como o onConflit está replace ele está sempre a substituir os items e sempre a actualizar
    }

    /**
     * Requests data from the API and increment the page in case of success
     * Save the fetched data into the database to allow offline usage
     */
    private fun requestAndSaveData(){

        //TODO ao atingir o total de páginas o isRequestInProgress estará a  null(o problema de estar sempre a actualizar vem daqui)
        if (isRequestInProgress) return
        isRequestInProgress = true
        getPosts(service,day,lastRequestedPage,BuildConfig.API_KEY, NETWORK_PAGE_SIZE,{ repos ->
            cache.insert(repos){
                lastRequestedPage++
                isRequestInProgress = false
            }
        },{error ->
            _networkErrors
            isRequestInProgress = false
        })
    }

    /**
     * static block to have the page size to the network calls
     */
    companion object {
        private const val NETWORK_PAGE_SIZE = 10
    }
}
```

This is my based paged adapter

```
abstract class BasePagedAdapter<T>(diffCallBack: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<T>) :  PagedListAdapter<T, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(diffCallBack){

    @LayoutRes abstract fun layoutToInflate(viewType: Int): Int

    abstract fun defineViewHolder(viewType: Int, view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder

    abstract fun doOnBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, item: T?, position: Int)

    final override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(layoutToInflate(viewType), parent, false)
        return defineViewHolder(viewType, view)
    }

    final override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        doOnBindViewHolder(holder, getItem(position), position)
    }

    fun retrieveItem(position: Int) = getItem(position)

}
```

This is my Adapter and ViewHolder

```
class PostAdapter : BasePagedAdapter<Post>(diffCallBack) {

    override fun layoutToInflate(viewType: Int) = R.layout.item_post

    override fun defineViewHolder(viewType: Int, view: View) = PostViewHolder(view)

    override fun doOnBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, item: Post?, position: Int){
        when(holder){
            is PostViewHolder ->{
                holder.setup(item)
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Its the first thing to start(like a static block in java)
     */
    companion object {
        val diffCallBack = PostDiffCallback()
    }

    class PostViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){

        private var dataBindig: ItemPostBinding = DataBindingUtil.bind(view)!!

        fun setup(item: Post?){

            /**
             * Variables defined in item_post.xml
             */
            dataBindig.title = item?.productName
            dataBindig.description = item?.tagline
            dataBindig.commentCountBinding = item?.commentsCount.toString()
            dataBindig.upvotes = item?.votesCount.toString()
            dataBindig.productImage = item?.postImage?.productLargeImgUrl
            dataBindig.userImage = item?.user?.imageUrl?.userLargeImgUrl
            dataBindig.userName = item?.user?.name



            if(diffCallBack.areContentsTheSame(item,item)){

                //TODO stop incrementing the page and stop all requests
            }

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the App, I see why the problem is happening. Each time the system updates from the service, the new items are placed before the item that the recycler is at. This means that it will always be at "the end". You can stop the infinite loop by setting a member variable in your `RepoBoundaryCallback` that will be set to the last product ID received in `onItemAtEndLoaded` from `itemAtEnd`. Only poll for new data if this product ID is different. My suspicion, is that you need to have some sorting on your local cache query to make sure that new entries are being inserted under your current row

Comment: Hello @Knossos, first of all thank you for the feedback I really aprecciate you helping and teaching others. Second of all, I tried to put a @Query("SELECT * FROM product_post WHERE day = :day ORDER BY votesCount DESC,name ASC") in my dao to have some sorting and the behaviour still persists. Do you have any clue?

Comment: Not immediately no, ordering by a timestamp would make most sense. However, it looks like the API gives back a "day" only? Which is inconvenient.

Comment: The api can also give me an created_at": "2017-09-14T06:02:04.954-07:00". I will try to do an ASC with this and get back to you

Comment: @Knossos it does not work with the SELECT * FROM product_post WHERE day = :day ORDER BY createAt DESC. In this example https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-paging/index.html#4 they dont use Timestamp, they only sort my vote_count and it works. I tried to replicate that into the projeto in the github repository you saw but has that behaviour.

Comment: @Knossos I find the solution. I saved the lastQueryValue() in the onSaveInstanceState and it seems to work and it seems to solve the issue. I updated my repository, if you want to take a look to see if it is a good approach :) Thanks so much for the help

Answer (score 0):

As your network page size is 10 so set Pagelist config as below to avoiding infinite/unnecessary call of **onItemAtEndLoaded** method

```
val config = PagedList.Config.Builder()
                .setPageSize(10)  //same as your page size
                .setInitialLoadSizeHint(10) //same as your page size
                .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
                .build()
```